# AudioNode clearing and disposal

Tags: audio, audiocontext, audiobuffer

Im trying to understand how garbage collection works here in audioNode. So if i go ahead and disconnect everything it will look like this. [Audio Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIPrr.png)

Will that ensure it gets garbage collected? Or is there more stuff that would could prevent this. If i look at my memory snapshot it looks like this. [Mem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eQvv.png)